# apache ssi include with file abc.inc fails (abc.html, abc.txt, abc.xxx, abc.INC works fine)

Tags: apache, server-side-includes

apache 2.2.15, +Includes in directory container and XBitHack Full

somefile.html has line <!-- #include file="abc.inc" -->
This include fails with "unable to include "abc.inc" in log

If I change the extension of the file (and the include statement) to virtually anything (e.g. abc.xxx, abc.txt, abc.html, even abc.Inc or abc.INC) everything works fine. ONLY abc.inc fails

I've looked for definitions of inc in mime.types, grep'ed everything in the httpd conf files/directories.

Not a huge problem but it's got me curious. 
thanks